# Django, queryset to return manytomany of self

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

Following regular manytomany queryset logic gives me errors. I guess since its related to self, I might need to do some extra magic, but i can't figure out what magic.

model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title   =   models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='title')
    related     =   models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='related_entries', blank=True)
```

queryset:

```
entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)
related = entry.related_entries.all()
```

error: **'Entry' object has no attribute 'related_entries'**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the documentation for the [`symmetrical`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) argument to `ManyToManyField`:

> When Django processes this model, it identifies that it has a ManyToManyField on itself, and as a result, it doesn't add a person_set attribute to the Person class. Instead, the ManyToManyField is assumed to be symmetrical -- that is, if I am your friend, then you are my friend.
>
> If you do not want symmetry in many-to-many relationships with self, set symmetrical to False. This will force Django to add the descriptor for the reverse relationship, allowing ManyToManyField relationships to be non-symmetrical.

So, in order to use the `related_name`, set `symmetrical=False`.

Comment: Right, now it stopped returning me the error. But now I have two entries. Say EntryA & EntryB. When EntryA has EntryB as related_entries, calling entry.related_entries.all() gives me nothing. But when EntryA has both EntryB, and EntryA (itself) as related_entries, calling entry.related_entries.all() only returns me EntryA, and not EntryB. *mindboggled*

Comment: Kasper: in that case, you want them to be symmetric: just delete the `related_name` instead, and use `entry.related.all()`